# How to sendmail after click button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodemailer

When I call sendMail function in contructor it working well but I call 
    that function when Click button it not working. I don't understand why? 
    Help me, please !

This is error message

```
request.js:150 OPTIONS https://api.nodemailer.com/user 405


Access to fetch at 'https://api.nodemailer.com/user' from origin 'http://localhost:3301' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`enter code here`
index.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: net.isIP is not a function
    at Object.push../node_modules/nodemailer/lib/shared/index.js.module.exports.resolveHostname (index.js:33)
    at SMTPConnection.connect (index.js:333)
    at index.js:263
    at index.js:70
    at run (setImmediate.js:40)
    at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js:69)
    at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js:109)
```

This is my javascript file:

```
const SmtpPage = Form.create({ name: 'SmtpPage' })(
  class extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: [],
      };
      this.sendMail(); // this is working well
    }

    sendMail = () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
      const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
      nodemailer.createTestAccount(() => {
        const message = {
          from: 'elonmusk@tesla.com', // Sender address
          to: 'to@email.com', // List of recipients
          subject: 'Design Your Model S | Tesla', // Subject line
          text: 'Have the most fun you can in a car. Get your Tesla today!', // Plain text body
        };
        const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
          port: 2525,
          auth: {
            user: '0130a10cc25c83',
            pass: '750ca28f3b6d1c',
          },
        });
        transport.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(info);
          }
        });
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <button  onClick={() => this.sendMail()}>
              Test Connection
           </button>
      );
    }
  },
);
export default SmtpPage;
```

when Click button it not working

Comment: Are you getting any error messages ? Also is there any particular reason why youre importing nodemailer in the send mail function instead of importing it on top ? also try onClick={this.sendMail}. Also try to include a console.log statement at the start of the function to see if the `onclick` event is being fired in the first place.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but just a point, you don't need to have this: `onClick={() => this.sendMail()}`, since there's no arguments to the function, You can just have this: `onClick={this.sendMail}`. This is also better cos the way you have it now is an anonymous function, which means it gets recreated on every re-render, so it's inefficient.

Comment: @Muljayan I see error message but it working in contructor

Comment: @Muljayan I'm testing so  importing nodemailer in the send mail function

Comment: @Muljayan  onClick function working because I call it in contructor working

Comment: Can you include the error message as part of the question too. Also try to do the following and tell us what happens. Remove functional call from constructor -> include a console.log('testing click') in the sendmail function -> click the button and see in console if 'testing click' is being logged

Comment: @Jayce444 I changed like you but it is not working

Comment: @Muljayan I changed erro message above and my onclick is working, it show 'testing click'

Comment: @Muljayan I was tested  transport.sendMail not working when I click button

Comment: Seems like its a CORS issue. Your browser is blocking the request because its CORS is not enabled. Try to search around how to overcome CORS issues when sending test mail using nodemailer.

Comment: @Muljayan ok I'm try, thanks you so much